# Getting the logged in user info from ADAL on android

Tags: android, active-directory, adal, oauth-2.0

I am working with ADAL from 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android

My code mimics the sample very close

```
        mAuthContext.acquireToken(ToDoActivity.this, Constants.RESOURCE_ID,
                Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.REDIRECT_URL, Constants.USER_HINT,
                new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception exc) {
                        if (mLoginProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            mLoginProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                TAG + "getToken Error:" + exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        navigateToLogOut();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
                        if (mLoginProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            mLoginProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        if (result != null && !result.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
                            setLocalToken(result);
                            sendRequest();
                        } else {
                            navigateToLogOut();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I pass in the user's email address, but if the user changes it and uses a different one the ADAL library on the onSuccess never tells me the user changed it. The AuthenticationResult has a field calls mUserInfo that that should contain user's first name/last name email etc.

But for me every successful login mUserInfo=null.

Anyone know how to get ADAL to return a fully populated mUserInfo object?

thanks
Tom

Comment: Are you running your code against AAD or adfs as an authority?

Comment: ADFS authority. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @tomhackbarth , did you figure out how to handle this? I'm facing the same thing. We can see that a user was authenticated but have no clue who they are.

Comment: see my answer here:
maybe will helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/a/43203464/1005462

Answer (score 0):

Userinfo is constructed from the ID_token retuned from the server. In case of adfs blue (3.0), it does not return an ID_token and hence you cannot truly know what user signed in at the IDP. Adfs threshold supports ID_token if you can upgrade.

Comment: by "ADFS theshold" do you mean ADFS 2016 and the OpenID/Connect flows?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Let me find out if there is any update to 3.0 that can help you get ID token

Comment: Sorry there is no support for Id token in adfs 3.0

Comment: @KanishkPanwar-MSFT , if `id_token` is not available in ADFS 3.0, how should an app using ADAL identify the user that was authenticated? We get an access token but even when we decode that we don't have anything in it that can distinguish one user from another. We have claims setup for the relying party but get no information in the access token.

Comment: Sub claim should identity the user.