# Identifier not found in Directory

Tags: android, azure

I am integrating Azure in my app.I have created app at Azure portal in Active directory and for integration using ADAL library but when i am running the app getting login screen of Microsoft and after login getting error this.

[i am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uDUY.png)

For login created button and onclick on button calling this

```
if (mResult != null) {
        // logout
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        authenticationContext.getCache().removeAll();
    } else {
        // login
       authenticationContext.acquireToken(LoginActivity.this,Constant.CLIENT_ID,
                Constant.CLIENT_SECRETE_KEY, Constant.REDIRECT_URL, "", PromptBehavior.Auto, "",
                callback);//CLIENT_ID=my appid at the of app registration //CLIENT_SECRETE_KEY=secret key of registered app in Active Directory //REDIRECT_URL=passing valid url
    }
```

and initializing authenticationcontext in oncreate() of LoginActivity

```
 authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(LoginActivity.this,
                Constant.AUTHORITY_URL, true);// Authority_URL=https://login.windows.net/mydirectoryname.onmicrosoft.com
```

for callback

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    authenticationContext.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void showInfo(String msg) {
    Log.e("", msg);
}

    private AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult> callback = new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exc) {
            showInfo("getToken Error:" + exc.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
            mResult = result;
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));


            if (mResult.getUserInfo() != null) {
                Log.v("", "User info userid:" + result.getUserInfo().getUserId()
                        + " displayableId:" + result.getUserInfo().getDisplayableId());

            }
        }
    };
```

and in Azure Portal in app registration grand the permission of KEYVAULT and MicrosoftAzureActiveDirectory (sign in and read user profile permission)
What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are probably wrong. Check this example on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android/blob/master/TaskApplication/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/test/todoapi/ToDoActivity.java#L188.

There it is done with:

```
mAuthContext.acquireToken(ToDoActivity.this, Constants.RESOURCE_ID,
                    Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.REDIRECT_URL, Constants.USER_HINT,
                    new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception exc) {
                            if (mLoginProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                mLoginProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    TAG + "getToken Error:" + exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            navigateToLogOut();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
                            if (mLoginProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                mLoginProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }

                            if (result != null && !result.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
                                setLocalToken(result);
                                sendRequest();
                            } else {
                                navigateToLogOut();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

---

You shouldn't have your client secret in the mobile app anyway. Anyone can unpack you application and find it.

Comment: What to pass in Constant.ResourceId and where to use ClientSecretKey in code

Comment: You don't use the client secret. You can't use it in mobile apps as they are running in an untrusted environment. The resource ID is the URI for the resource you want an access token for. So e.g. `https://graph.windows.net/` for Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: authenticationContext.acquireToken(LoginActivity.this,Constant.RESOURCE_ID,
 Constant.CLIENT_ID, Constant.REDIRECT_URL, "", PromptBehavior.Auto, "",
 callback);
 i used this Authority_Url=https://login.windows.net/(mydirectoryname).onmicrosoft.com
 this Redirect_url="https://(mydomainname)/users/auth/azure_oauth2/callback"
 this resource id="https://login.windows.net/(mydirectory_id)/oauth2/token"
 but getting AADSTS50001 error*

Answer (score 0):

if (result != null && !result.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
is wrong, add token null check or add getStatus success check...

yes, ms special create bad android sample [ I think :) ];

simplest way is open your app creted under AD and open edit manifest:
from sample:
AUTHORITY_URL - is "identifierUris" from app manifest (not android manifest; add-manifest from ad registered web-api app);
CLIENT_ID - is appId;
RESOURCE_ID - is from manifest too;
 "requiredResourceAccess": [    {      "resourceAppId":  some times it comes in auth ex message;

and you should add same reply Url at AD app too;

if redirect after auth directly to todoactivity for some reason result failed status, but if open add user you can see there sign-in user info and sign in success status;

So after fix that sample it works at all, but it was a hard 1-2 days brainstorm;
expected more form ms sample, looks like with each year qulity is go momre and more low;